# no value found after parsing json file in Racket

Tags: json, racket

I have the following code:

```
#lang racket

(require json)

(define test-json (read-json (open-input-string (file->string "test.json"))))
(hash-ref test-json "foo")
```

test.json

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "bar":"baz"
}
```

No I'm getting this error: `hash-ref: no value found for key, key: "foo"` but in test.json there is a value assigned.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried different versions to import the json file but same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json module's `jsexpr` format uses [symbols for object keys](https://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html#%28tech._jsexpr%29), not strings. You can also pass [`read-json`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._json%2Fmain..rkt%29._read-json%29%29) a file input port directly instead of reading a file as a string and then using a string input port.

You should be doing something like:

```lisp
(define test-json (call-with-input-file "test.json" read-json))
(hash-ref test-json 'foo) ; "bar"
```